# Can I rely on recipients deduplicating emails with the same Message-Id?

Tags: email, distributed

In developing a system that sends out or relays emails, network timeout by the remote (SMTP) host or a system failure at critical moments can lead to a resolution where it's impossible for the sender to determine if the email has been forwarded.

In order to implement guaranteed delivery, at-least-once semantics seems to be the likely option.  In regards to this, is it reasonable to assume that deduplication will occur somewhere downstream if the same `Message-Id` is used when re-sending emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deduplication by using `Message-ID` *could* be performed by specific mail clients, but the RFC for SMTP makes no mention of this.   Instead, it states implementations should strive on reducing the critical timing:

RFC 5321 "Simple Mail Transfer Protocol" under **[6.1.  Reliable Delivery and Replies by Email](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-6.1)** reads:

> To avoid receiving duplicate messages as the result of timeouts, a
> receiver-SMTP MUST seek to minimize the time required to respond to
> the final <CRLF>.<CRLF> end of data indicator.  See RFC 1047 for
> a discussion of this problem.

And RFC 1047 "DUPLICATE MESSAGES AND SMTP" states under **[AVOIDING SYNCHRONIZATION PROBLEMS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1047)**:

> The best way to avoid the synchronization problem is to minimize the
> length of the synchronization gap [in the state between the final dot].  In other words, receiving mailers
> should acknowledge the final dot as soon as possible and do more
> complex processing of the message later.

Answer (score 0):

Deduplication eliminates duplicate or redundant information. As far as SMTP servers are concerned they just check the authenticity of sender, integrity/quality of data in email. That is, they check whether the mail is legitimate and valid to be delivered to recipient.

I don't think `Message-ID` is checked on delievert/transport server for every message which needs to be delivered. Its the responsibility of MUA(Mail User Agent) or MSA(Mail Submission Agent) to ensure the uniqueness of every mail's `Message-ID` which it sends out.